# Should I use Create React or Next JS (with client side rendering) for an admin site?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, create-react-app

I have an eCommerce store built with Next JS and Django. I would like to now migrate from using the Django admin site to using a sleeker, more interactive React admin site and am trying to decide on which to use between Next JS and Create React -- I don't need the SEO but even after reading countless articles and watching countless videos on YouTube, I still don't know why else I would choose one over the other and which is best suited for my application. It feels to me like Create React is equivalent to Next JS using client side rendering (i.e. fetch and the useEffect hook).

The reason for not integrating the admin into the Next JS app is because it's just so much easier for me to consider it as a separate app especially when it comes to security and handling authentication. And Typescript types would clash a lot if I combined them. Also, would AWS charge me double for having two apps? That could be another decisive factor.

* I know this is opinion based, but they're invaluable to me at this point.

Answer (score 2):

If you know about React or Next.js then choose that framework. In addition, if you are using AWS for hosting your web applications then charges are calculated according to your resource usage, so before choosing any one of the frameworks just calculate and have some knowledge on the AWS billing cycle. This will be helpful for your project cost.